# Event Listener on dynamically created elements only working for first result

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have my event listener working on my dynamically created HTML, but the problem I'm having is that it is only always listening to the first result.

For Example, The value 'this.id' are different;

> IMAGE (hidden value = '3')
>
> IMAGE (hidden value = '6')
>
> IMAGE (hidden value = '8')

However no matter the image I click, value 3 is always selected. How can I solve this problem?

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JavaScript (dynamically creating HTML)

```
var html =
'<form action="test.php" method="get" id="myForm">' +
  '<input type="hidden" name="mID" value"' + this.id + '"/>' +
  '<input type="image" id="send" src="this.image" name ="send"  alt="submit"/>' +
'</form>';
$('div#test').append(html);
```

AJAX

```
$("#test").on('click', '#send', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

            $.get( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
                    $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
                    function(data) {            
                      console.log(data);
                        });

            $("#myForm").submit( function() {
               return false;
            });
```

});

Comment: man id is unique for element try class

Comment: Use delegated handler to handle the submt event also...

Comment: ID of an element must be unique so use class instead of ID... `$("#myForm")` will select only the first element with the ID `myForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of static ID for element which are added multiple times. ID of an element must be unique in a document, the ID selector will fetch only the first element with the given ID. So in your case when you say `#myForm` it will always return the first `myForm` in the page.

Instead you can use class selector, and you can lookup the form to which the clicked `send` element belongs using `closest()` like

```
var html =
  '<form action="test.php" method="get" class="myForm">' +
  '<input type="hidden" name="mID" value="' + this.id + '"/>' +
  '<input type="image" class="send" src="this.image" name ="send"  alt="submit"/>' +
  '</form>';
$('div#test').append(html);


$("#test").on('click', '.send', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $form = $(this).closest('form');

  $.get($form.attr("action"), $form.find(":input").serializeArray(), function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
$("#test").on('submit', '.myForm', function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi @Arun thanks for your reply. I tried you code suggestion but it didn't work :( with your code the page just goes straight to the php page (test.php), almost like the JavaScript isn't there.

Comment: Actually my bad.. IT WORKED!! I had an error in my code which I fixed.. Thanks a lot @Arun.